# Twitter API request to adaptive.json

Tags: python, json, api, twitter

Recently took a look at the Twitter module of [snscrape](https://github.com/JustAnotherArchivist/snscrape). Inspecting the source code, I noticed that it makes requests to the url https://api.twitter.com/2/search/adaptive.json which is not documented anywhere on Twitter's developer area. What is this resource, and how is it used?

Answer (score -2):

The reason that this is not documented on the developer site is that it is not a supported API endpoint. Using this endpoint is likely to result in a block on your IP address. You should only use the supported public APIs.

Comment: It would be great if you block the endpoint or restrict somehow from others. I have seen a application doing it. It looks they have far way advantage using that API than the supported APIs. This hurts other businesses who is depending on twitter APIs. I am happy to share the URL to you where it is being used. Thank you.